# Why can't I alter a security policy conditionally?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

I have the following rather simple statement in SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2016 CTP 3.2:

```
if exists(select null from sys.security_policies where name = 'OrganisationSecurityPolicy')
begin
    alter security policy [security].OrganisationSecurityPolicy
    with (state = off)
end
```

A security policy with that name does indeed not exist so nothing should happen. However, I get an error:

```
Msg 33268, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot find the object "security.OrganisationSecurityPolicy" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Is there something special about security policies that makes this impossible? If I replace the `alter security policy` with an `alter table` for a non-existing table, the statement simply isn't executed.

Comment: Perhaps you have the incorrect schema in the `alter security policy...` statement?  Note you are not checking the schema name in the `if exists(...)` statement.

Comment: The security policy exists in the `security` schema. The name in `sys.security_policies` is without the schema. So everything is correct there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements go through three processing steps - parsing, binding and execution, in that order. This batch is failing at binding since it cannot find an object to match the typed words. The work-around is to use dynamic SQL.

See a related question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89240/alter-table-statement-failed-msg-207-level-16-state-1/89253#89253).

Comment: I'm now using dynamic SQL and this works (of course). It seems a bit random to me which statements fail during parsing and which in a later stage. An `alter table` for a non-existing table instead of `alter security policy` doesn't have this problem. I don't see the logic there...

Comment: I would have thought it was the difference between DML (optimised and hence bound) and DDL (not optimised or bound). But [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879314.aspx) states `ALTER SECURITY POLICY` is DDL. Go figure.